# Is it possible to specify interpolation method for zoom functions in Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD)?

Tags: geoserver, interpolation, sld

To visualize images on Geoserver, I use xml file wrote in Styled Layer Descriptor (http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld). I would like to specify what interpolation method would be used for zoom functions. Can I write it in xml SLD ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, not part of the SLD 1.0 spec, nor GeoServer has any vendor extension allowing this.